# module to safely delete obsolete drupal database tables

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7

does anyone know of an existing module or script that will remove or identify obsolete tables in a drupal database?

The site has been upgraded from drupal 5 to 6 and 6 to 7. I know that there are many tables that are not in use or were not removed when uninstalling custom modules.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Schema module](http://drupal.org/project/schema) provides some useful reporting on mismatches between the schema that has been declared in your installed modules versus the schema as it exists in the database. That would be a good start in identifying obsolete tables.